# OpenCV argc and argv confusion

Tags: c, opencv, argv, argc

I'm checking some OpenCV tutorial and found this line at the beginning (here is the link, code is under the CalcHist section http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/histograms.html)

```
if (argc == 2 && (src = cvLoadImage(argv[1], 1)) != 0)
```

I've never seen this before and really don't understand it. I checked some Q&A regarding this subject but still don't understand it.
Could someone explain to me what is the meaning of this line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line does the following, in order:

1. Tests if `argc == 2` - that is, if there was exactly 1 command line argument (the first "argument" is the executable name)
2. If so (because if `argc` is not 2, the short-circuiting `&&` will abort the test without evaluating the right-hand-side), sets `src` to the result of `cvLoadImage` called on that command-line argument
3. Tests whether that result (and hence `src`) is not zero

`argc` and `argv` are the names (almost always) given to the two arguments taken by the `main` function in C. `argc` is an integer, and is equal to the number of command-line arguments present when the executable was called. `argv` is an array of `char*` (representing an array of NULL-terminated strings), containing the actual values of those command-line arguments. Logically, it contains `argc` entries.

Note that `argc` and `argv` always have the executable's name as the first entry, so the following command invocation:

```
$> my_program -i input.txt -o output.log
```

...will put 5 in `argc`, and `argv` will contain the five strings `my_program`, `-i`, `input.txt`, `-o`, `output.log`.

So your quoted if-test is checking first whether there was exactly 1 command-line argument, apart from the executable name (`argc == 2`). It then goes on to use that argument (`cvLoadImage(argv[1], 1)`)

Checking `argc` and then using `argv[n]` is a common idiom, because it is [unsafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behaviour) to access beyond the end of the `argv` array.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the "if so" in point 2 refers to the fact that the `&&` operator is short-circuiting, i.e. evaluation will stop if `argc == 2` is false.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. It confused me because I've never seen this before. So my next question would be - why to use syntax like this?

Comment: Like which? The use of `argc` and `argv`, or the assignment-then-test of `(src = cvLoadImage()) != 0`?

Comment: Yes, like that. Can you explain why to use arc and argv, where is the image reading part?

Comment: @Moirae - there we go, more deatail on argc, argv added. Does that clear everything up?

Comment: @Moirae - No worries. Remember you can Accept my answer (green checkmark) to say it helped.